# Laravel 9 in docker cannot connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and I try to dockerize laravel9 app.
Here is my Dockerfile at the project root

```
# Set master image
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/html/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install Additional dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    build-base shadow nano  curl 
   

# Add and Enable PHP-PDO Extenstions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

# Install PHP Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Remove Cache
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Add UID '1000' to www-data
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

# Change current user to www
USER www-data

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Then my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  #Laravel App
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: compagnon-backend/laravel
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - mynet  
      
  #Nginx Service
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
    networks:
      - mynet
    
  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laraveldb
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: laravelpassworddb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpasswordmysql
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql/
    networks:
      - mynet

#Docker Networks
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

Then my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:8z6QUUPvvVEZY9UmsWGE7o8LmkmcdQiDjSqvFKfznPo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://compagnon-backend.fr

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laraveldb
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=laravelpassworddb
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

the docker-compose build command succeeds
After having launched docker-compose up -d

I use these commands

```
docker-compose exec app php artisan config:cache
```

OK.

```
docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate
```

This command fails with this message

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '172.21.0.3' is not allowed to connect to
> this MySQL server (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where
> table_schema = laraveldb and table_name = migrations and table_type =
> 'BASE TABLE')

What is wrong ?

Comment: You can't access your database from outside, it only allow 127.0.0.1, you will need to allow it, use something like : `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'172.0.0.0/255.0.0.0';`

Comment: Your user creds are different for MongoDB instance and in .env file. Check the username, dbname and the like. The `root` user  might not have access

Comment: O! user root was just a trial I made. In fact I use user=laravel and password=laravelpassworddb.  BTW why this values for host 172.0.0.0 ? And how can I dot this (GRANT ...) from inside the container ?

Comment: I dont' get you. To run the command, you should connect to the docker container, but it's not required for now. So did you fix the issue?

Comment: Not yet. But I make progress in my understanding. I could connect to the msql containerr with docker-compose exec db bash and then connect to mysql. But what troubles me is the fact that contrarily to the tutorial I am following, there is no laraveldb database created.

Comment: Eventually I restarted the tutorial from scratch and now it works ! The only thing that bothers me is that I could not make out where was my mistake.